# failing to run a specific version of mysql on my mac

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I have two versions of mysql:

```
~ » brew info mysql                                                                                                                                                                  nirohayon@Nirs-MBP-2
mysql: stable 8.0.12 (bottled)
Open source relational database management system
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/
Conflicts with:
  mariadb (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same binaries.)
  mariadb-connector-c (because both install plugins)
  mysql-cluster (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same binaries.)
  mysql-connector-c (because both install MySQL client libraries)
  percona-server (because mysql, mariadb, and percona install the same binaries.)
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.20_1 (323 files, 234.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-01-09 at 16:39:57
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.11 (254 files, 232.6MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2018-12-26 at 20:33:05
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘
Required: openssl ✔
==> Requirements
Required: macOS >= 10.10 ✔
==> Caveats
```

when I switch to `5.7.20_1` - i go `mysql.server start` all good and `mysql` open the shell.

when I switch to `8.0.11` - i go `mysql.server start` i get en error:

> ... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file
>   (/usr/local/var/mysql/My-MBP-2.pid).

i dont get it, what do i miss here?

Comment: how do you switch?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run two instances of mysql on the same data directory.

The pid file is used to guarantee that only one `mysqld` process is running at the same time on the same database.

If you want to run both MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8, you have to define two different data directories.